# How to enable display scaling beyond the default cap?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display-settings, scaling

I have a PC running Windows 10 that has its "Size of text, apps and other items" setting capped at 125%. I need more. How can I unlock higher scaling values?

I'm talking about this slider:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open Registry Editor (regedit).
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
3. In right-side pane, look for `Win8DpiScaling` and set the value to 1
   and close Registry Editor.
4. Restart your computer.
5. Open the Control Panel (icons view) and select Display.
6. Under `Change size of items`, click on the `set a custom scaling level`.
7. Drag the ruler left or right to the scaling percentage you want.
   (Alternatively, select the scaling percentage you want in the drop
   down menu)
8. Click on Apply.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hm, I've had a feeling that custom scaling works slightly different from that main scaling slider, resulting in slightly more things being broken in different programs. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings select System and, on the left, click on Display.

Under Scale and layout, in the Change the size of text etc. box you can set the scaling up to 175%.

Comment: But what if I need more? On some displays Windows lets you go up to 300%.